# Where should my `fetch` request be placed in my React app without having to pass data between the child and parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project right now, where I have `App.jsx`, and my other components `inputComponent` and `articleComponent`. `App.jsx` contains both my `inputComponent` and my `articleComponent`. However, I've written the `fetch` request to be within `inputComponent`.

In this case, my `articleComponent` relies heavily on the data retrieved from the `fetch` request, and so I'm thinking, a possible solution would be to move the `fetch` from `inputComponent` to `articleComponent`. Another one was to use callbacks to pass data from the child component to the parent component. However, based on some answers I've read here and online, it seems that this method of passing data from the child component to the parent is a React anti-pattern as well.

I also think that the `fetch` call ideally shouldn't be on `App.jsx`, but feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Ideally, what I need is for the data retrieved from the `fetch` call (which comes from user input submission in `inputComponent`) to be able to be passed in as props to the `ArticleComponent` so that I can render the articles with the proper data after fetching it from my server. What would be the "React" way of doing it, and also the best way in general?

Comment: `However, based on some answers I've read here and online, it seems that this method of passing data from the child component to the parent is a React anti-pattern as well.` I definitely wouldn't say this is universally true. Child components pass information up to parent components all the time, and it's often a necessary part of the design of a system. That decision must be done on a  case-by-case basis

Comment: Hey @TKoL, do you have any examples in which this would be necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @misternobody said, the 'normal' way is to pass data down to children as props and yes, if a parent's state change - it re-renders all of its children (that's the idea behind React).

So you would pass your input from `inputComponent` up to `App` (with the use of a callback passed as a prop), `fetch` inside your `App`, then pass the response down to `ArticleComponent`

If for some reason you want to dodge the rendering of `App` component in this process, you'd have to use ie. `Redux` and NOT connect `App` to the store. Then, if you'd properly map store's state and diapatch to props in your 'child' components, it should work as you intended without bothering `App`.

Comment: I went with this solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally the properties you want in all children sit in the parent class.

I would write the fetch right there, and pass it to the children as props.

Comment: Won't this cause the entire parent to re-render with everything everytime I call `setState`?

Comment: @bryancresswell No, you can use built in methods like componentWillUpdate (check them up). Basically, you compare the state of 2 different moments, and select when something renders or not.